# NSString to PDF file - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

I'm receiving a String from a web service and I would like to store it as a pdf file.

I know the have asked before but the answer is always the same. I've tryed it and didn't worked, and it's not explained enough.

So, this is what I'm doing:

```
NSData *data = [documentString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *formattedName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", name];
NSString *pdfPath = [@"documents/" stringByAppendingPathComponent:formattedName];
NSError *error = nil;
if([data writeToFile:pdfPath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error]) {

}
```

It's not entering in the if, and I think the file is not being generated.

I'm working with objective-c, xcode 9.

What should I modify?

Comment: print the error may be file path is incorrect

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16806796/485174

Comment: @Sh_Khan "The folder “myname.pdf” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSFilePath=documents/myname.pdf, NSUserStringVariant=Folder, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000006587e0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}} You're right but I don't understand, why should it exists? I want to create it

Comment: your path to documents is incorrect

Comment: @JaimeAlcántaraArnela reference this link => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437809/print-pdf-file-on-iphone-or-ipad/35601056#35601056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create it

```
NSError*error=nil;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Application Support"];

NSString*filePathC = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"historyImages"]];


if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:filePathC])
{
    if(

       [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePathC
                                 withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                                  attributes:nil
                                                       error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"created");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"not created");
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"exists");
}
```

///

```
  NSData *data = [documentString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSString *formattedName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", name];
  NSString *pdfPath = [filePathC stringByAppendingPathComponent:formattedName];
  NSError *error2 = nil;
 if([data writeToFile:pdfPath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error2]) {

 }
```

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting for so long. I've tried it, now it creates the path and the pdf, but I've gone to the path and tried to open the file manually. It said that "it could not be opened" with the default from mac, opening with atom I see that it's only a file with all the bytes from the string. So, do you know what I'm doing wrong? It seems that it didn't traduce correctly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I was encoding the data wrongly. The correct way was: NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:documentString options:0]; So it's fixed, thanks